# Android WiFi Device-to-AP Round-Trip-Time (RTT)

Tags: android, wifi

With Android `API-Level 21`, respectively 23 some methods to measure the Wifi `roundtrip time` (RTT) were added to the SDK:

- [WifiManager.isDeviceToApRttSupported()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html)
- [ScanResult.is80211mcResponder()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html#is80211mcResponder())

But I do not find any information how to use the API to measure the `RTT`.

The relevant class [RttManager](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-7.0.0_r6/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/RttManager.java) is still marked as System API.

Is there any way to perform `Device-To-AP RTT` measurement?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Starting with `Android P` a public API for Wi-Fi RTT (IEEE 802.11mc) is now available.

[WiFiRttManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/rtt/package-summary.html)

Add the following to your AndroidManifest:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi.rtt" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Get instance of WiFiRttManager:

```
final WifiRttManager rttManager = (WifiRttManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_RTT_RANGING_SERVICE);
```

Check if device supports Rtt measurements:

```
rttManager.isAvailable();
```

Perform a ranging:

```
// A ScanResult can be retrieved by e.g. perform a WiFi scan for WiFi's in range -> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html 
final RangingRequest request = new RangingRequest.Builder()
                               .addAccessPoint(scanResult)
                               .build();
final RangingResultCallback callback = new RangingResultCallback() {
    public void onRangingResults(List<RangingResult> results) {
        // Handle result, e.g. get distance to Access Point
    }

    public void onRangingFailure(int code) {
        // Handle failure
    }
};
// Start ranging and return result on main thread.
rttManager.startRanging(request, callback, null);
```

**Please notice that the Access Point has to support Wi-Fi RTT (IEEE 802.11mc) as well!**

**Update: A sample app can be found here:** [Android Wifi RttManager sample](https://github.com/Plinzen/android-rttmanager-sample)

Comment: Brother, I need more information. Can you please provide sample source code for this?

Comment: Where exactly do you get stuck?

Comment: 1. (Context.WIFI_RTT_RANGING_SERVICE) - am getting red underline error here.

2. How to get the "scanResult"? Will be helpful if you give example of it.

Comment: 1. do you use AS 3.2 Canary?
2. Perform a Wifiscan. There are plenty of tutorials about it. No need to repeat it here.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Thank you. Will do that.

Comment: The error is basically just a Lint Error. Since Android P is still under development, I'd ignore it.

Comment: please, I faced the same issue such that I want to compute WiFi RTT from my smartphone to WiFi AP, but
1- the following code has error (     mwifirttManager = (WifiRttManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_RTT_RANGING_SERVICE);
),
where the wifirttmanger can not be resolved!!

2- Can I implement Wifi RTT on my device (Samsung  Note5, API 23, Android 6)?

Comment: No, for the new API a phone with Android P is required. You can try to use the hacky way mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39720803/2960788

Comment: I want to develop an android application on my device (Samsung Note 5, API 23, Android 6), such that I can scan the surrounding WiFi Access points and send Packets to each one AP from the smartphone, then compute the RTT time delay propagation in ms for all observed APs.  Could please tell me if this is possible to be implemented and supported by android platform or not ?

Comment: Does someone know which devices support RTT at this time?

Comment: e.g. the Pixel devices

Comment: Does someone know where you can buy an Access Point that supports IEEE 802.11mc?

Comment: Only Pixel devices so far? When I try to get the system service for the RTT service I get a null pointer to the `WifiRttManager` (using a Xiaomi Mi 8 with Android P ROM). Any idea why?

Comment: @Tobbe, any luck finding AP that supports IEEE 802.11mc?

Comment: @mgfernan only this one https://fit-iot.com/web/wifi-indoor-positioning/ but I haven't tested it. Google Wifi will support it [EOY 2018](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/googlewifi/siswi-8oPGs;context-place=topicsearchin/googlewifi/category$3Aapp%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false)

Comment: @Christopher why **context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_WIFI_RTT);** i am getting always false

Comment: @k_kumar but your phone(s) are supporting this feature? Which phone did you test?

Comment: MI android version 9

Comment: Since there are quite a lot of Mi phones out there, I guess yours doesn't have the required hardware built-in. Try a different one, eg Google Pixel 2 or up.

Comment: @k_kumar m getting the same thing did u found any solution ?

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a small libary to wrap the hidden API calls within an Compat class:

[Android RttManagerCompat](https://github.com/Plinzen/android-rttmanager-compat/)

The lib makes use of Java Reflection to get access to the API and basically it seems to work.

Update:

- The app has to be installed in the system/priv-app/ folder
- Therefore the phone needs to be rooted.

Update:

- Android P provides a public API, which makes that library obsolete.